# How to navigate to data URL?

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, data-uri

I am making am making a data URL generator, and I am making the link to the generated data URL. Here is some sample code that links to a data URL.

```html
<a href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCI+CjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjI1MCIgY3k9IjI1MCIgcj0iMjEwIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iOCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K">Click this link</a>
```

The problem though, is that when you click the link, nothing happens.

I tried setting `location.href` to the data URL.

```html
<!--this doesn't work-->
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); location.href='<data url here>'">Click this link</a>
```

`window.open` opens `about:blank`.

```js
// Opens about:blank
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCI+CjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjI1MCIgY3k9IjI1MCIgcj0iMjEwIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iOCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K");
}
```

There are a few exceptions though. When you drag the link to the URL box or to a different/new tab, it works, but then most people don't bother to drag a link. But if the page is in an `iframe`, you can click the link.

```html
<a href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCI+CjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjI1MCIgY3k9IjI1MCIgcj0iMjEwIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iOCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K">
  Because this snippet is shown in an iframe, you can click this link.
</a>
```

But then it doesn't show the data URL in the URL box. I tried using `location.pushState` and `location.replaceState`, but you can't change the URL in the URL box to a page to an external page. **Basically *every single answer on Stack Overflow to every single question like this* puts the data url in an iframe in some sort of way. It just doesn't work because the url is just about:blank. It just doesn't work.**

So how do I navigate to a data URL? What have I not tried to do to navigate to a data URL? Any help would be great.

**Note:** I am using Microsoft Edge/Chromium 103

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCI+CjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjI1MCIgY3k9IjI1MCIgcj0iMjEwIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIiBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iOCIvPgo8L3N2Zz4K";

const _window = window.open();
_window.document.write('<iframe src="' + data + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKRED.png

Comment: Iframes don't work, because the url in the url box is still `about:blank`, not the data url

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you want to open in new tab and show the svg? If yes, then this answer should be solve your issue Do you try my answer code?

Comment: I tried your answer, and it works, but the point also is that the data URL is in the address bar, not just displaying the image. I have seen lots of answers to similar questions that do the same thing.